# Calculating the mean of truncated log normal distribution

Tags: math, scipy, statistics

I am trying to calculate the mean of a truncated log normal distribution.
I have a random variable `x` which has a Log-Normal distribution with std `a`.

I would like to calculate the mean of `x` when `x < y`

Note - If `x` was normally distributed, it can be calculated using [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) library:

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
my_mean = 100
my_std = 20
myclip_a = 0
myclip_b = 95
a, b = (myclip_a - my_mean) / my_std, (myclip_b - my_mean) / my_std
new_mean = truncnorm.mean(a, b, my_mean, my_std)
```

I would like to convert this code with the assumption that the distribution is Log-Normal and not Normal.

Answer (score 0):

There may well be more elegant ways of doing this, but I ended up reverting to integrating the lognormal pdf multiplied by x over the range between the truncated outcomes to solve this problem before.

Below is a Python example - ignore the clumsy way I've specified the untruncated lognormal distribution mean and standard deviation, thats just a peculiarity of my work.

It should work between any truncations (x1 = lower limit, x2 = upper limit) including zero to infinity (using np.inf)

```
import math
from scipy.special import erf
import numpy as np

P10 = 50                         # Untruncated P10 (ie 10% outcomes higher than this)
P90 = 10                         # Untruncated P90  (ie 90% outcomes higher than this)
u = (np.log(P90)+np.log(P10))/2  # Untruncated Mean of the log transformed distribution
s = np.log(P10/P90)/2.562        # Standard Deviation

# Returns integral of the lognormal pdf multiplied by the lognormal outcomes (x)
# Between lower (x1) and upper (x2) truncations
# pdf and cdf equations from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution
# Integral evaluated with;
# https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bexp%5C%2840%29-Divide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29ln%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29-u%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C%5C%2840%292*Power%5Bs%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D
def ln_trunc_mean(u, s, x1, x2):
    if x2 != np.inf:
        upper = erf((s**2+u-np.log(x2))/(np.sqrt(2)*s))
        upper_cum_prob = 0.5*(1+erf((np.log(x2)-u)/(s*np.sqrt(2)))) # CDF
    else:
        upper = -1
        upper_cum_prob = 1

    if x1 != 0:
        lower = erf((s**2+u-np.log(x1))/(np.sqrt(2)*s))
        lower_cum_prob = 0.5*(1+erf((np.log(x1)-u)/(s*np.sqrt(2))))
    else:
        lower = 1
        lower_cum_prob = 0

    integrand = -0.5*np.exp(s**2/2+u)*(upper-lower) # Integral of PDF.x.dx

    return integrand / (upper_cum_prob - lower_cum_prob)
```

You could then evaluate - for example, the untruncated mean as well as a mean with upper & lower 1 percentile clipping as follows

```
# Untruncated Mean
print(ln_trunc_mean(u, s, 0, np.inf))
```

27.238164532490508

```
# Truncated mean between 5.2 and 96.4
print(ln_trunc_mean(u, s, 5.2, 96.4))
```

26.5089880192863